# Memory (RAM) How it is represented

Tags: memory, byte, cpu, bit, ram

in Intel64 CPUs I learnt that each address is 8 bytes (64 bits) plus I learnt that the smallest unit with address is byte (8 bits) so does this mean acceessing one byte directly is allowed or I have to read 8 bytes at once?

Answer (score 0):

- The smallest unit that you can access is a *BYTE = 8 BITS*.
- But the address of this *BYTE* in memory(RAM) consists of 8 bytes (=64 bits) on the Intel x64 architecture.

So, to access one *BYTE*, you have an address of 8 *BYTEs* locating this special *BYTE*. But *internally* the processor reads more than this single BYTE, IIRC a cache line of 64 BYTEs (for this single BYTE).

Comment: Is this related to what I read before than when accessing one index at the array accessing the one next to it is faster since the cpu reads nearby memory which is the other 7 bytes in this case? or that the cpu reads more than 8 bytes?

Comment: Yes. The bytes "next" to it are read from the cache and not from the RAM which is faster than accessing the RAM again. The assumption is that data is often read sequentially, or, at least, from the same area.